# Blend curves in Blender like Illustrator does

Tags: geometry-nodes, procedural

I have two shapes - A and B - in Illustrator. I can blend from A to B in Illustrator easily. Can I do this in Blender? Preferably in a generative way, so I can later animate as you can see in the GIF. In Cinema 4D I would just use Cloner with Blend mode and put both splines in. Color is just for demonstration, it can be just white. I’ve tried a few GeoNodes tutorials on Youtube and also Google, but with no luck whatsoever. Thank you guys!

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This GN group:

- Resamples 2 cyclic input curves, to match resolution.
- Creates a set of curve-circles at the same resolution, stashing their point indices before duplication, to get an "point index-per-duplicate"
- Using *Sample Index*, transfers a mix of the input curves' point-positions to the duplicates. using the stashed indices as target, and a mapping of the 'Duplicate Index' as mix-factor.

[image]

The curves can be animated, and the blend will respond accordingly. The Mix Factor is also stored on the generated splines, so can be used by shaders:

[image]

.. quite hard to crunch into a nice .gif.

But here's the file:

[image]