# Blend curves in Blender like Illustrator does, but with more steps inbetween

Tags: geometry-nodes

I found here [this interesting solution](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/289709/blend-curves-in-blender-like-illustrator-does).

That's great node solution! However, I would like to ask you if it's possible to push that even further. What I mean is that here we have only 2 curve shapes initially, but waht if I would like to have more, like 3 or 4 or more steps? I tried to mix in one more, but it doesn't make a trick. Ideally I would like to have 1 on the bottom, 2nd one a bit higher and moved to the left for instance, 3rd step goes again higher and to another side and so on if I would like to have mulitple steps in between, do you undestand what I mean? The so to say tower of curves goes to different directions dependeing on where 3rd one or more are located in between.

I don't know how to mention [Robin](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/35559/robin-betts), but I hope someone else could answer.

Comment: You can mention @RobinBetts like this ;)